# datepicker сломался на удаленном сервере

Tags: angular, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

Писал инпут с datepicker-ом от ngx-bootstrap, на локальном сервере все хорошо играло, выложил сайт в интернет и datepicker вместо названия месяца, номера недели, числа ставит просто буквы M, W, D соответсвенно. В итоге вместо календаря у меня ровная таблица букв. Особенность еще в том, что на локальном сервере все работает как надо.
Никаких ошибок консоль не выдаёт.
Почему так?..

Comment: а вы локально АОТ компилировали?

Comment: AOT - это не она, это компиляция шаблонов компонентов до рантайма